# If function is concave in each of its variables keeping the rest fixed, is the function concave.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f(x,y) : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

If the function is concave in each of its variables keeping the other fixed, is the function $f(x,y)$ concave?

That is,  if we have:

$f(x,c)$   $\quad \forall c \in \mathbb{R}$ is concave w.r.t $x$

$f(c,y)$   $\quad \forall c \in \mathbb{R}$ is concave w.r.t $y$

Is $f(x,y)$ concave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For instance $f(x,y)=xy$.

Comment: How about the case where we have strict concavity.